# How to send post request to external api in aws lambda with nodejs 10x?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am trying to send post request to an external api in aws lambda using nodejs 10.x. But I am getting error

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Converting circular structure to JSON",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Please find the code below:

```
const http = require('https');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const req = http.request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', (res) => {
            resolve(res);
        });

        req.on('error', (e) => {
          reject({error: e.message});
        });

        // send the request
        req.write('');
        req.end();
    });
};
```

I am expecting json response like below

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `http.request` without adding options object but a URL. You should replace it with `http.get` or add options object.

You are also resolving response from http request without building the data. If you are using Lambda behind API Gateway proxy integration then response should be formatted. Following code should work.

```
const http = require('https');

let getData = () => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', (resp) => {

      let data = '';

      resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });

      resp.on('end', () => {
        resolve(data);
      });
    }).on('error', (e) => {
      console.log('Error', e.message);
      reject(e);
    });
  });
};

module.exports.handler = async (event) => {

  try {
    // Data is string.
    const data = await getData();
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: data
    }
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: e.message
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi @A.Khan that worked as expected. I am new  to lambda functions can you also give an example for post request in lambad functions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm running this on Lambda but then get "errorMessage": "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead" response. Any help?